# OpenGL-ES 2.0 blend 2 textures and save the result into a original texture

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, alphablending

I am a newbie to OpenGL ES 2.0, I have read this thread about how to blend 2 textures into a final framebuffer result. [How do I blend two textures with different co-ordinates in OpenGL ES 2.0 on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242443/how-do-i-blend-two-textures-with-different-co-ordinates-in-opengl-es-2-0-on-ipho)

My current requirement is a little different.

I want to blend texture called inputTextureTop(Varying) and texture inputTextureBot(constant) and save the result into texture inputTextureTop.

It should be simple enough. How do I modify the sample code in the thread to try?

Objective C code...

```
    - (void) display {
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, targetFBO);

        glUseProgram(program);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureTop);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureBot);

        glUniform1i(inputTextureTop, 2);
        glUniform1i(inputTextureBot, 3);

        glUniform1f(alphaTop, alpha);

        glEnable (GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        glVertexAttribPointer(position, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, imageVertices);
        glVertexAttribPointer(inputTextureCoordinate, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureCoordinates);

        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
        [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
    }
```

Vertex Shader code:

```
    attribute vec4 position;
    attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

    varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = position;
        textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
    }
```

Fragment shader...

```
    varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

    uniform sampler2D inputTextureTop;
    uniform sampler2D inputTextureBot;

    uniform highp float alphaTop;

    void main()
    {
        lowp vec4 pixelTop = texture2D(inputTextureTop, textureCoordinate);
        lowp vec4 pixelBot = texture2D(inputTextureBot, textureCoordinate);

        gl_FragColor = someBlendOperation(pixelTop, pixelBot);
    }
```

Thanks so much!

Regards,

Howard

========================
Updated on August 22nd.

After some investigation, I found it's a dead path. There is no way to composite texture (top) + texture (bottom) and change to texture (top).

However, there is a way to composite texture (top) + texture (bottom) and save it to texture (target).

The way to do it is to bind a target texture to the same framebuffer that texture top and texture bottom uses.

Add the code below will do the job:

```
      glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); 
      bindTexture(textureTarget); 
      glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureTarget, 0);
```

The result will be stored in textureTarget.

Bingo.

Answer (score 1):

To render into a texture is more complicated because you must use an FBO.  This can be done with either OpenGL ES 2.0 or 1.1 (with extensions). This article explains in detail:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Render_to_Texture_with_OpenGL_ES

Also, see my answer here for an example of combining 2 textures in shader code:

[OpenGL ES 2 : use an additional texture unit to blend this image with the current one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890271/opengl-es-2-use-an-additional-texture-unit-to-blend-this-image-with-the-curren/17892307#17892307)

Comment: After some investigation, I found it's a dead path.

There is no way to composite texture (top) + texture (bottom) and change to texture (top). However, there is a way to composite texture (top) + texture (bottom) and save it to texture (target).

The way to do it is to bind a target texture  to the same framebuffer that texture top and texture bottom uses. Add the code below will do the job:

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    bindTexture(textureTarget);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureTarget, 0);

Comment: Can someone unban my account? I posted the answer in the question. Somehow, my account is banned. Please do. B/c it's a valid answer and I got the problem solved.